# How to insert a date into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to insert date and time into a cell of an Excel spreadsheet. `NOW()` and `TODAY()` don't fit my needs. These functions insert dynamic date. But I want static: if I insert the date it won't change with time.

Answer (score 28):

To insert the current date, hold control and press the semicolon key.  This will quickly insert the current date in a non-dynamic way.

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> will insert the date
<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> will insert the time.

Comment: for me, this simply does not work. It worked before my last windows reinstall. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Type it.

Make sure to set the cell type as date.

(Mokubai's answer is much better though!)

Answer (score 1):

You can *copy* > *paste special* > *value* then it won't change. You can use this for all sorts of formulas, such as `RAND()`.