# How to automatically insert today's date so it does not change in the future?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert a date into an Excel spreadsheet?](https://superuser.com/questions/246039/how-to-insert-a-date-into-an-excel-spreadsheet)

For example, I have the formula `=NOW()` but I want the date to be fixed as today's date. I don't want it to change tomorrow.

Is there a way to change the formula to make sure it only reflects the date today? Or how can I do that?

I don't want to Paste Special if possible.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with keyboard commands.

To enter current date: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>
To enter current time: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

> F9 followed by ENTER (or followed by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for array formulas) calculates the selected a portion of a formula and replaces the selected portion with the calculated value.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP001111659.aspx

Do it on your =NOW() formula, and it should stay fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I would try inserting the current date into a cell via a macro. The question then only is, when and how to trigger that. You could for example press a button and it would insert today's date (not as a formula) into a cell (one particular or the selected one).

In VBA you can use `Now()`, `Date()` and `Time()`, depending on what you need exactly.
With `Range("d40").Value = Date()` associated to a shape it will insert the current date without the time into Cell D40 when you click the shape.